# WP_Query in functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-query

I've got some code that I want to turn into a function. It works great until I wrap it in said function:

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
        'post_type'         =>  'asset',
        'category_name'     =>  $cat
    );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $matching_category_ids = array();       
    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
        array_push($matching_category_ids, $post->ID);
    endwhile;
```

The function looks something like this:

```
function grab_ids_in_category($cat) {
    //stuff from above here
    return $matching_category_ids;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, you're addressing `$post` out of context.

When you're running a standard WordPress loop, WP will load a global `$post` variable with the results of the current query.  This includes the ID, title, content, post meta, etc.  The loop functions will reference this global variable to actually give you data.

Take the regular function `get_the_ID()` for example:

```
function get_the_ID() {
    global $post;
    return $post->ID;
}
```

Your code will work fine outside of a function because, somewhere in the code above it, you're probably `global`izing the `$post` variable.  So your direct reference to `$post->ID` works.

But when you wrap this code inside a function, you *aren't* referencing `$post` as a global, so `$post->ID` won't return anything because the *local* `$post` is undefined.

Instead of referencing `$post->ID` directly, use the regular loop function `get_the_ID()`:

```
while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
    array_post( $matching_category_ids, get_the_ID() );
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the global variable $post into the function like this:

```
function grab_ids_in_category($cat) {

    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
        'post_type'         =>  'asset',
        'category_name'     =>  $cat
    );

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $matching_category_ids = array();

    while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
        array_push($matching_category_ids, $post->ID);
    endwhile;

    return $matching_category_ids;

}

// echo the Query and pass a category name 
echo grab_ids_in_category('category_name');
```